# how to convert time in unorthodox format to timestamp in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have a column in my dataframe which I want to convert to a Timestamp. However, it is in a bit of a strange format that I am struggling to manipulate. The column is in the format HHMMSS, but does not include the leading zeros.

For example for a time that should be '00:03:15' the dataframe has '315'. I want to convert the latter to a Timestamp similar to the former. Here is an illustration of the column:

```
message_time
25
35
114
1421
...
235347
235959
```

Thanks

Comment: Does `25` mean `2:05:00`, `2:00:05`, `00:02:05`, or `00:00:25`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) for add leading zero and then [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
s = df['message_time'].astype(str).str.zfill(6)
df['message_time'] = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%H%M%S')
print (df)
         message_time
0 1900-01-01 00:00:25
1 1900-01-01 00:00:35
2 1900-01-01 00:01:14
3 1900-01-01 00:14:21
4 1900-01-01 23:53:47
5 1900-01-01 23:59:59
```

In my opinion here is better create timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
s = df['message_time'].astype(str).str.zfill(6)
df['message_time'] = pd.to_timedelta(s.str[:2] + ':' + s.str[2:4] + ':' + s.str[4:])
print (df)
  message_time
0     00:00:25
1     00:00:35
2     00:01:14
3     00:14:21
4     23:53:47
5     23:59:59
```